# Compiling error (called function is not an object)

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code for poissons equation. I have written the code but it is giving a compiling error of 'called function is not an object or function pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int U[101][101];
    int Unew[101][101];
    double Nx = 100, Ny = 100;
    float tol = 0.00001;
    float L = 2.0;
    int i, j;
    float pi = 3.14;
    float Dx, Dy, x, y;
    Dx = (L / Nx) + 1;
    Dy = (L / Ny) + 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
        for(j = 1; j <= 101; j++) {
        }
    }
    x = (i - 1) * Dx;
    y = (j - 1) * Dy;
    for(i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
        for(j = 1; j <= 101; j++) {
            U[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    for(i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
        U[i][1] = 0.0;
    }
    for(j = 1; j <= 101; j++) {
        U[101][j] = 0.0;
    }
    for(i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
        U[i][j] = 0.0;
    }
    double iter;
    double residual;
    for(iter = 1; iter <= 10000; iter++) {
        for(i = 2; i <= 101; i++) {
            for(j = 2; j <= 101; j++) {
                Unew[i][j] = (Dy * Dy * (U[i - 1][j] + U[i + 1][j]) + Dx * Dx * (U[i][j - 1] + U[i][j + 1]) -
                              Dx * Dx * Dy * Dy * (cos(pi * Dx) * sin(pi * Dy) + pi * pi * cos(pi * Dx) * sin(Dy))) /
                             (2.0(Dx * Dx) + (Dy * Dy));
            }
        }
        if(Unew[i][j] - U[i][j] <= tol)
            break;

        else {
            iter = iter + 1;
        }
        U[i][j] = Unew[i][j];
    }
}
```

It gives an error

```
Unew[i][j]=(Dy*Dy*(U[i-1][j]+U[i+1][j])+Dx*Dx*(U[i][j-1]+U[i][j+1])-Dx*Dx*Dy*Dy*(cos (pi*Dx)*sin(pi*Dy)+pi*pi*cos(pi*Dx)*sin(Dy)))/(2.0(Dx*Dx)+(Dy*Dy));
```

> called function is not an object or function pointer

Comment: A little more formatting woun't have hurt. :(

Comment: Are you serious? You want help (btw debugging help is not appreciated) and do not even format your code to be readable?

Comment: `(2.0(Dx * Dx) + (Dy * Dy));` -> you forgot a `*` between `2.0` and `(Dx...`. Even you teacher allows that in math it is not allowed in C to "forget" the multiplication sign

Comment: So sorry fr not doing the proper formatting..thanks fr ur answer, it helped..can u please tell me how to get the results now? Because im new to programming..Im using linux..i ran the code after compiling bt it gave nothing..please help..thanks.

Comment: I definitively wont read and understand the code for you and seek your error. Thats your work, no mine... But I give you a hint: Without any function that outputs text, of course you wont get any results printed to your console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is near the end of the line:

```
(2.0(Dx*Dx)+(Dy*Dy))
```

You need an operator between `2.0` and the parenthesis.
I guess you are missing a `*`?

**Note:**

I compiled it with `gcc` and got the much clearer error message:

> error: called object '2.0e+0' is not a function